# Symfony 4 & Amazon S3 - AWS credentials not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, ubuntu, amazon-s3

I have a Symfony 4 project that is deployed to the Digital Ocean Ubuntu server.
In order to store files, I am using Amazon S3 bucket.
I've used `aws/aws-sdk-php` library to interact with the Amazon S3 bucket.
I've created the global credentials file at ~/.aws/credentials and managed to make it work.

The problem is that it doesn't work on the server.
I copied the credentials file to the server's ~/.aws/ directory, but I am getting this error.

```
Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. (Client error: `GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response: not found)
```

I did some research on this error - it seems that the php server isn't finding the credentials file.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All AWS SDKs search for credentials from various sources in a specific order of priority. You can see this order in the [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html).

Typically, if the SDK is unable to find *any* credentials from any of the sources in which it searches, then it reports an error retrieving credentials from the final credential provider in its search list, and that's usually (and perhaps always) STS credentials from the instance metadata service.

In your case, you're not even running on AWS so the instance metadata service is not relevant and the error message you see is a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

Here is what I suspect is happening: you are trying to supply credentials via a `~/.aws/credentials` file but the AWS PHP SDK is not finding credentials there. So, one of the following may be happening:

1. your PHP application is running as a different Linux user and hence its home directory is not the same as the one you placed the `.aws/credentials` file in
2. your `~/.aws/credentials` file is invalid in some way or has zero credentials in it (unlikely, I would say)

My vote is on #1.

Comment: Hi, @jarmod. Thanks for your explanation. Your first opinion is really interesting. I am accessing the console as the root user, but the PHP server is running as the "deploy" user from the CI/CD pipeline. So I copied the ~/.aws/credentials file to the /home/deploy/.aws/credentials, but still getting the error. Any idea?

Comment: One more strange thing is that my first approach was to use the .env file in the project directory, but it didn't work. So I moved to the global credentials approach, but still not working. Both approaches are working on my local. Is it possible that this error has occurred from the permissions issue? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe add additional code to your PHP app temporarily to list the files in `~/.aws/`and cat/print the contents of `~/.aws/credentials` to make sure they are what you think they are. Just to verify that it does have access to a valid credentials profile (but it's not using it).